# Usage the ADDTIME() function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update

I need using on MySQL the **ADDTIME()** function for adds a time interval to a time/datetime and then returns the time/datetime.

This is my MySQL table

```
+-----+---------------------+----------+-----+
| m   | mDate               | mDatenew | sID |
+-----+---------------------+----------+-----+
| 182 | 2020-06-04 20:15:00 | NULL     |   1 |
| 173 | 2020-06-13 21:35:13 | NULL     |   2 |
|  74 | 2020-06-13 16:22:50 | NULL     |   3 |
+-----+---------------------+----------+-----+
```

I need update the values of columns `mDatenew` with the value of colum `mDate` adding the value in minute of column `m`

First the update I have tried this query for check values but the return is null

```
mysql> SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(
        ADDTIME(mDate, m),
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
    ) AS t
FROM
    `n`;
+------+
| t    |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set
```

How to do resolve this?

My table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `n`;
CREATE TABLE `n` (
  `m` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `mDatenew` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of n
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `n` VALUES ('182', '2020-06-04 20:15:00', null, '1');
INSERT INTO `n` VALUES ('173', '2020-06-13 21:35:13', null, '2');
INSERT INTO `n` VALUES ('74', '2020-06-13 16:22:50', null, '3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need update the values of columns `mDatenew` with the value of colum `mDate` adding the value in minute of column `m`.

MySQL understands date arithmetics with intervals. You can increment the date as follows:

```
mDate + interval m minute
```

If you want an `update` statement:

```
update n set mDatenew = mDate + interval m minute
```